# Laravel validation check unique with combination of constant

Tags: laravel

I have L5 model with fields email and app_name.
I would like to check unique combination of email which is input from form and for app_name, its constant always.So it should be combination of email and app_name = 'MYAPP'. Please suggest how to achieve this using validator.

Comment: If your `app_name` is constant, then you just have to check for unique `email` as the combination will be unique only if the `email` is unique.

Comment: Refer [docs] (https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-unique) for `unique` validation.

Answer (score 0):

If your `app_name` is constant, then you just have to check for unique `email` as the combination will be unique only if the `email` is unique.

Checking for unique `email` -

Inside the validator or Request class

```
'email' => ['email', 'unique:users,email,' . $this->route('users') . ',id'],
```

I am assuming the following:

- Table name for users is `users`
- Column name for email is `email` and id is `id`.
- Routes are generated using `Route::resource`